# Position:Fixed; Scaling Methods for Web Browsers

Tags: css, header, browser, scaling, fixed

I'm experimenting with a position:fixed; #header of 100% width and 50px max-height. On full screen for most web browsers I can't gaurantee the content of the layout in the #header will be congruent, however, it will most likely fit the page. The much larger concern however, is upon resize the content of this will look a complete mess. Does anyone have a method they're comfortable with that would scale this content?

Here is a small basic sample of what I'm doing

```
/* --- Footer/Header Area --- */ 
#footer {
height: 70px;
max-height: 70px;
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
background-color: #eee

}

#header {

background-color: #fff;
height: 50px;
max-height: 50px;
line-height: 45px;
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
float:left;
box-shadow: 2px 4px 5px #555;

}



#header img {

/* --- TOGOHERE: >>>> margin: 10px 30px 0 --- */

}

#header h1 {
display:inline-block;
font-size: 1.2em;
font-family:Courier New;
text-align: left;

} 

#header h2 {
display:inline-block;
font-size: x-small;
font-family: Tahoma;
text-align: center;
padding-right:2cm;
}

#header h3 {
display:inline-block;
font-size: xx-small;
font-family: Tahoma;
text-align: center;
padding-right:2cm;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use alternative container size for each media query. one for large screens, one for medium, one for small and one for extra small.

Comment: Would this be a formatting selector, or something I apply as attributes to a div? Does my question make sense?

Comment: Give a div a class of say container then use media queries to change the size of the container based on screen width

Comment: Sorry meant different size containers for each size look up twitter bootstrap 3 and you can see how they do it. Or just use that framework watch a few videos its very helpful TB3